# Typescript API ts.transpileModule transpiles window path "\\" to empty string "" -- is this expected? Is it a bug?

Tags: typescript, windows, filepath, transpiler

The phenomena was observed running in windows, where the string "..\y" was naturally create from `path.join("..","y")`.

However it can also be observed in Linux running this code as a test:

```
import ts from 'typescript'
const compopts = {};
const out = ts.transpileModule('import x from "..\\y"\n console.log(x);\n',{});
console.log(out); // ... var __y_1 = require("..y");  The "\\" has been elided
```

Typescript is developed by Microsoft as open software, and they develop Typescript on Windows so AFAIK they broadly support windows style paths when running on Windows.  Therefore I was very surprised when testing my Linux developed program on windows to find this seeming incompatibility with windows paths.

Is this expected?  Is it a bug?

---

EDIT:
As Kevin suggested in the comments, I will use `/` instead of `\\`

Since I have been using nodejs `path` functions such as `join`, I will keep code change to a minimum by replacing

```
path.<whatever>
```

with

```
path.posix.<whatever>
```

which will work for relative paths to be passed through `ts.transpileModule`.

Fortunately I have no absolute paths to deal with, e.g., `C:\\y`, because `path.posix` doesn't handle letter drives.

How to deal with letter drives (when passing through `ts.transpileModule`) is a question that remains to be answered.

Comment: Yes, that seems strange...  I would use the forward slash instead.  `/`

Comment: @Keith - Good idea.  The funny thing is I had been been carefully programming paths using the nodejs "path' module functions because I believed the result would be compatible with window, iOS, and Linux.   But instead, I have to go back and hard code in '/', which I had deliberately avoided.  This is confusing.

Comment: Yes, it's caught me out a few times with paths, when mixing Windows / Linux.  I would say this is a bug with Typescript, noticed it doesn't do this if the module type is ES..  maybe worth reporting..

Answer (score 1):

You didn't use enough backslashes.

As some comments have already pointed out, it's easier and far more portable to just use forward slashes.  But you *could* use backslashes for your Windows-only scripts, if you use twice as many of them. [†](http://it-was-just-a-tooltip)

This is something that catches pretty much every Windows developer off guard every now and then.  Because backslashes have special meaning within strings in most programming languages, Windows paths are notoriously difficult to deal with, and many languages have explicit string literal forms that disable the special behavior of backslashes, just to make this less of an issue.  For instance, C# has "verbatim" strings, marked with an "at" symbol, such as this:

```cs
var hostsFile = @"C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts";
```

Meanwhile, Python has "raw" strings, marked with a leading `r`:

```py
hosts_file = r"C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"
```

In JavaScript, there's `String.raw`:

```js
const hostsFile = String.raw`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`;
```

Let's go back and look at your code.

```js
const out = ts.transpileModule('import x from "..\\y"\n console.log(x);\n',{});
```

Instead of `ts.transpileModule`, let's just call `console.log`.

```js
console.log('import x from "..\\y"\n console.log(x);\n');
```

The output we'd get from that probably looks a bit like what you think you're looking for:

```
import x from "..\y"
 console.log(x);
```

Except, maybe now you see the problem.  Because backslash is a special character, that's not how you'd actually write an import.  You'd probably normally write it with two backslashes.

```
import x from "..\\y";
console.log(x);
```

Because the path is inside a string literal, you'd have to escape the backslash by doubling it.  But now you've got your string literal embedded *inside another string literal*, so you need to double the backslashes again.

```js
console.log('import x from "..\\\\y"\n console.log(x);\n');
```

This would actually give you what you're looking for:

```
import x from "..\\y"
 console.log(x);
```

But it would be far easier to use `String.raw`:

```js
console.log(String.raw`import x from "..\\y"\n console.log(x);\n`);
```

```
import x from "..\\y"\n console.log(x);\n
```

Oops!  Now the escape codes we actually *wanted* didn't get processed!

If you ask me, that's actually **better**, because `\n` is much harder to read than an actual newline.  So, with `String.raw`, you'd want to write your embedded code in a way that was easier to read, anyway:

```js
console.log(String.raw`
import x from "..\\y";
console.log(x);
`.trim());
```

```
import x from "..\\y";
console.log(x);
```

Or if you want it to look really nice:

```js
console.log(String.raw`
    import x from "..\\y";
    console.log(x);
`.trim().replace(/^    /gm, ''));
```

All that said, you're **still** better off using forward slashes in your imports, just for cross-platform compatibility (and it's a little easier to type, too).  But even so, using `String.raw` for long, multiline string literals makes them much easier to read and maintain.  Plus, it would allow you to use interpolation, which is something you'll likely want if you're doing something like this.